# What's a better solution than manual/gasoline corn and bean seeder?

Tags: seeds, tools, beans, corn, electric

I already asked on  [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169668/adapt-electric-motor-to-manual-seeder) how to adapt an electric motor to a manual seeder.

I followed the advice of a commenter to ask on this site, so that people here may have a better solution for the problem at hand.

So, please, do you have a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You'd basically have to rebuild the tool from the ground up. It would be easier to stick a drill/spacer system on an already powered motorized machine.

What I find is that if the soil is properly worked and smoothed, these manual seeders work quite well. I use one that is almost 40 years old. And if you're working an area too large for that to be practical, a gasoline powered self propelled seed drill would be perfect.

I absolutely do not see any way to create a DIY practical electric powered seed drill.